# No difference between Thin & Light fontWeight on iOS when adding custom font to my react-native app

Tags: ios, fonts, react-native, custom-font

I just added a custom font to my react-native app (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Josefin+Sans).

```
JosefinSans-Bold.ttf
JosefinSans-BoldItalic.ttf
JosefinSans-Italic.ttf
JosefinSans-Light.ttf
JosefinSans-LightItalic.ttf
JosefinSans-Regular.ttf
JosefinSans-SemiBold.ttf
JosefinSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
JosefinSans-Thin.ttf
JosefinSans-ThinItalic.ttf
```

I linked the font files by running `react-native link` after adding

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": [
    "path/to/my/font/files"
  ]
},
```

to my `package.json`

I then use the font in my app like so:

```
customFont: {
    fontFamily: 'Josefin Sans',
},
thin: {
    fontWeight: '100'
},
light: {
    fontWeight: '300'
},
semiBold: {
    fontWeight: '600'
},
bold: {
    fontWeight: '700'
},
italic: {
    fontStyle: 'italic'
},
```

[iOS simulator screenshot of the different fontWeight and fontStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYLE4.png)

The problem is that there is no difference between the `thin(fontWeight: '100')` & the `light(fontWeight: '300')`.

What I've tried so far:

- Tried with another font from google fonts (same problem).
- Tried to run the app on an actual device (rather than the simulator) but in vain.
- Tried to use iOS default font with those fontWeights: `thin` and `light` are really recognizable
- Displayed the font actual names (`JosefinSans-Light` and `JosefinSans-Thin`) in xcode with:

_

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
  NSLog(@"%@", family);
  for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
  { NSLog(@"  %@", name); }
}
```

Has anybody had the same issue ?
Any ideas on how to fix it and display the actual thin and light font weights ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to use a different `fontFamily` style for each weight when it comes to custom fonts.

So in this case, you would want something like this for your styles (names may be slightly off, but you get the idea):

```
customFont: {
    fontFamily: 'Josefin Sans'
},
thin: {
    fontFamily: 'Josefin Sans-Thin'
},
light: {
    fontFamily: 'Josefin Sans-Light'
},
semiBold: {
    fontFamily: 'Josefin Sans-SemiBold'
},
bold: {
    fontFamily: 'Josefin Sans-Bold'
},
italic: {
    fontFamily: 'Josefin Sans-Italic'
}

...
```

Of course, feel free to add additional styles as you deem fit. Also, you may want to change `customFont` to `regular` in light of this.

Comment: Hi TheJizel, thanks for your answer !
Actually, for most weights it seems to work with the fontWeight property.
For instance, the `fontWeight: '600' renders the same as `fontFamily: Josefin Sans-SemiBold` and the `fontWeight: '900' renders the same as `fontFamily: Josefin Sans-Black`.

However I still don't see any difference between `Josefin Sans-Thin` and `Josefin Sans-Light` :(

Comment: @guitoof Can you try changing the font names so that there is no whitespace (e.g., `JosefinSans-Thin`)? That was my issue when I was using Open Sans.

Comment: TheJizel thank you. yes I try that too but I understand that the important thing is that on Android the fontFamily prefix should match the name of the file. Therefore, if my file is named `Josefin Sans_bold.ttf` I use `fontFamily: Josefin Sans_bold`. So no luck here ... :(

Comment: Have you able to resolve the issue of fonts? In android, the fonts are based on the name of the file ex. 'my_font.ttf', while IOS targets with the name 'My Font'